# Definition of prime subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've got a pretty weird definition of a prime subfield in my lecture.

First we defined a ring homomorphism...

$f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow K$ in which $K$ is a field, $f(0)=0_K$, $f(n)=\underbrace{1_K+...+1_K}_{n}$ and $f(-n)=-f(n)$ $\forall n$

1. Then we showed that if $f$ is injective, we can define an injective field homomorphism $\bar{f}:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow K$ so that this diagram is commutative:

[image]

2. If $f$ is not injective, we can define an injective ring homomorphism $\bar{f}:\mathbb{Z}/\ker f\rightarrow K$ that makes this diagram commutative:

[image]

Lastly, we defined the prime subfield as $im(\bar{f})$.

---

I know an equivalent definition: "The prime subfield of a field $K$ is the subfield generated by $1_K$"

I get that $im(\bar{f})$ basically means that we have an subfield $L\subseteq K$ that's isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
Does the commutative diagram mean that I can display every $x\in L$ with a combination of $1_K$?

Comment: I disagree, this is not "pretty weird". It shows in addition that we have only two choices for the prime field, namely $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well yes but from my perspective I only see the prime field as a subfield in $K$ that's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$. I don't really see how it's generated by $1_K$ or how it's the intersection of all subfields of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the subfield from the "weird" definition $F_C$, the field generated by $1_K$ as $F_I$, and the intersection of all subfields as $F_S$. Proof that these are all equal:

Since $1_k\in F_C$, we have $F_I\subseteq F_C$, and $F_S\subseteq F_I$ by definition.

If we ask for the minimum field containing $1_K$, then we need to include $1_K+1_K$, and $1_K+1_K+1_K$, etc. For all such elements, we also need their additive inverse to be in $F_I$. That means we can define $f':\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow F_I$ in the same way as you defined $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow K$, and this is a ring homomorphism. In fact, $f'(n)=f(n)$ for all $n$. So $f'$ is injective if and only if $f$ is, meaning we can lift $\overline{f}'$ into $F_I$ into the same way. But since the action of $f'$ is the same as $f$, then $\overline{f}'(x)=\overline{f}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$), since the lifting $\overline{f}$ is unique. This means:

$$ F_C=\overline{f}(\mathbb{Q}) = \overline{f}'(\mathbb{Q})\subseteq F_I$$

(or replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

Finally, note that any subfield $K'$ of the field $K$ must contain $1_K$, so it must contain the field that $1_K$ generates. Thus, $F_I\subseteq K'$ for all subfields. This means $F_I\subseteq F_S$, the intersection of all subfields.

Intuitively, $1_K$ is going to generate an additive group, and this is going to look like $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. In the second case you're done because it will also be multiplicatively closed. In the first case you will also need the inverses of all those elements, which will look like fractions in $\mathbb{Q}$. Specifically, the field of fractions (the minimal field containing such a ring) will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$.